# Jquery Button to make visible a form

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, forms

I want to ask about how to make a form invisible when a button clicked? So, if I have a button called "Hide" and a form with many button, textbox, etc.

Then when I click "Hide" button, it will hide all form and all things in form such as textbox, button, etc. I have google it but have no result. I accept answer with Jquery, JS, or php language because I'm using that language program.

Example my form is like this:

```
<form name="myform" method="post" action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>ID</td>
            <td>:</td>
            <td><input type="text" maxlength="15" name="clientid" /></td>
            <td><input type="submit" name="cariclientid" value="Search" /></td>
            <td width="50px"></td>
            <td>ID</td>
            <td>:</td>
            <td><input type="text" maxlength="15" name="orderid" /></td>
            <td><input type="submit" name="cariorderid" value="Search" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>No.</td>
            <td>:</td>
            <td><input type="text" maxlength="15" name="veh" /></td>
            <td><input type="submit" name="carikendaraan" value="search" /></td>
            <td></td>
            <td>Nama Sopir</td>
            <td>:</td>
            <td><input type="text" maxlength="15" name="sopir" /></td>
            <td><input type="submit" name="carisopir" value="Cari" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Waktu Berangkat</td>
            <td>:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="tglb" id="datetimepicker" /></td>
            <td><input type="submit" name="cariberangkat" value="Cari" /></td>
            <td></td>
            <td>Waktu Pulang</td>
            <td>:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="tglp" id="datetimepicker2" /></td>
            <td><input type="submit" name="caripulang" value="Cari" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

maybe there's a way to make it invisible by a button?

Comment: `$('button').click(function(){ $('form').toggle(); });`

Comment: Seriously consider using field-sets instead of putting your form in a table.

Comment: @deed02392 I have created all the search form like this... so I can't change to fieldset. Thanks for recommendation.

Comment: Why this question has 4 upvotes is beyond my understanding.

Comment: @itachi You get a hat for upvoting a bunch of questions/answers. This question is in the "hot" list, so it gets targeted, I'll assume. =)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You want something like this:

```
// code for only hide
$('#hide_button').on('click', function() {
  $('form[name="myform"]').hide();
});
```

***[Demo for hide](http://jsfiddle.net/ggdK7/1/)***

and for toggle the form with a single button you can try:

```
$('#your_button').on('click', function() {
   $('form[name="myform"]').toggle();
});
```

***[Demo for toggle](http://jsfiddle.net/ggdK7/2/)***

---

According to *[comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13948165/jquery-button-to-make-visible-a-form/13948191#comment19235652_13948191)*

To prevent the submission:

```
$('form[name="myform"]').submit(function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   // Your code
});
```

See here for ***[.perventDefault()](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/)***

Comment: @CeliaTan check the above demo and comment if there is any issue.

Comment: I don't know why but the code isn't works for me... It reload a page (i see flickering) but the form still showed up

Comment: @CeliaTan post your button code.. i think it possess the `type="submit"`.

Comment: How about returning false from the click event to prevent submission?

Comment: Ah, I put the submit... It works now, but I can't get the value that I want from the form that I hide (im using php, method post and that's why i put submit to get a value from that form)

Comment: It showed error... Well, it's hard to explain what I want. But the core is, I want to make a button that make my form invisible, and get the value of button (is it pressed or no) if it pressed then it runs this code : header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel"); according to Your code, I placed it at //Your code but it showed error... Sorry for my bad English

Comment: @thecodeparadox Sorry if it's hard, but thank You for Your answer, right now I'm using 2 button, one to hide it and one to submit it... Hope You can find another solution. But I really do appreciate Your kind answer right now...

Comment: @CeliaTan its no hard.need to see the button you're using..then I may help you  out/